# An issue evaluating RegionInteresect

Tags: regions

**Description:**

I am trying to find a `RegionIntersect` between a `Disk` and a `Polygon`. I have noticed, the code crashes when `Disk` would originate near a corner. Please see example below.

**Code:**

```
r1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 29}, {12, 29}, {12, 14.5}, {9, 14.5}, {9, 0}};
iwork = {1, 4};
idont = {1, 1};
```

**Example 1:**

```
(*This produces expected result*)

Graphics[{
  {FaceForm @ White, EdgeForm @ Black, Polygon @ r1},
  RegionIntersection[Disk[iwork, 4], Polygon @ r1]
  }]
```

**Note:**

`RegionIntersection` produces:

```
DiskSegment[{1, 4}, 4, {\[Pi] + ArcTan[Sqrt[15]], 3 \[Pi] - ArcTan[Sqrt[15]]}]
```

**Output 1:**

[image: working example]

**Example 2:**

```
(*This code produces unexpected result*)

Graphics[{
  {FaceForm @ White, EdgeForm @ Black, Polygon @ r1},
  RegionIntersection[Disk[idont, 4], Polygon @ r1]
  }]
```

**Note:**

`RegionIntersection` produces:

```
RegionIntersection[Disk[{1, 1}, 4], 
 Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 29}, {12, 29}, {12, 14.5}, {9, 14.5}, {9, 0}}]]
```

**Output 2:**

[image: not working example]

Why `RegionIntersect` does not evaluate when origin is near corner? How could this code be changed to retrieve similar result as with `Circle`.

**Circle Alternative:**

[image: circle alternative]

**Reference:**

[Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)
[Polygon](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html?q=Polygon)
[Disk](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html?q=Disk)
[Circle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html?q=Circle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say in your post, for some cases, `RegionIntersection` is able to return a `Graphics` primitive

```
RegionIntersection[Disk[iwork, 4], Polygon@r1]
(* DiskSegment[{1, 4}, 4, {π + ArcTan[Sqrt[15]], 
  3 π - ArcTan[Sqrt[15]]}] *)
```

to which you can simply apply `Graphics` and get a visual result.  This is not the general case.  If you took those regions and created `MeshRegion` objects first, it would not work

```
With[{rr = 
   RegionIntersection[DiscretizeGraphics@Disk[iwork, 4], 
    DiscretizeGraphics@Polygon@r1]},
 {rr, Graphics@rr, RegionPlot@rr}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But you can see that `RegionPlot` can take a `Region` and create a `Graphics` object from it (not a `Graphics` primitive, mind you).  Then you combine it with the other shape with `Show`

```
Show[
 Graphics[{FaceForm@White, EdgeForm@Black, Polygon@r1}], 
 RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[Disk[idont, 4], Polygon@r1], 
  PlotStyle -> Black, BoundaryStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you @JasonB. This makes things a little bit clearer. How does it decide if output is `Graphics` or `Region`? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about it

Comment: Not sure, it must have some internal methods to check.  So the safest route would be to always use `RegionPlot`

Comment: see here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricSpecialRegions.html. Certain graphics primitives *are* regions, so you can safely assume the output of `RegionIntersection` (if valid) is a region.  `DiskSegment` is new in 10.2 BTW.